# ImportError at / No module name ___ even though requirement satisfied

Tags: python, django, module, pip

I'm runnning a django app and getting this error:

```
ImportError at /
No module named svglib.svglib
```

my code for importing this is:

```
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
```

when I run `pip list` I see that I have `svglib (0.8.1)` installed already.

Is this due to the import being in parent.file format? What is work around  here?

EDIT: I have Django 1.11.8 and Pip 9.0.1

Comment: you probably have >= 2 different python versions installed

Comment: What version of python is Django using, and what version of python is pip using?

Comment: @JohnGordon I have Django 1.11.8 and Pip 9.0.1.

Comment: @Chris_Rands that doesn't sound good. How can I check this / do you know what the fix is?

Comment: @benjo `import sys; print(sys.version, sys.executable)`

Comment: Try to install `pip install svg2rlg` directly

Comment: For install  `pip install svg2rlg` maybe you need install after `pip install reportlab`

Comment: I wasn't asking the pip and django versions themselves; i was asking for the **python version** those two things are using.  You can see the pip python version by running `pip --version`.  Finding out the django python version is tricker; it's probably simplest to make a small view function that displays the value of `sys.version`.

Comment: @JohnGordon Gotcha -- pip 8.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7) , and then >>> django.VERSION
(1, 11, 8, u'final', 0) I believe

Comment: I think my problem is bigger than this one package -- trying to install other packages is giving me the same "No module named" error, even through theyre already intalled

Comment: Again, that's the version of django, not the version of python that django is using.  `sys.version`, not `django.version`.  (And you can't just run that in a python shell, because you don't know for sure if that's the same python version that django is using.  You have to make a view function.)

Comment: @JohnGordon Ok: '2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) \n[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]'. Also my Django debug page says "Python Version: 2.7.12". Thank you

Comment: Hmm.  Those are both python 2.7, so I'm stumped.

Comment: start from scratch: create a new virtualenv and reinstall Django and your packages using pip with that new virtualenv active. Then try running your app from within that virtualenv

Comment: Ultimately, I decided to just not use the package